# Name error:Uninitialised constant-Rails namespaced modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninitialized-constant

I have rails app in that I have namespaced all modules required. The modules are not loading and getting `Name error Uninitialised constant Udp`

```
/app/adapters/Udp/     #Here Udp is the module name
```

contains two files.

first.rb

```
module Udp
  class First        #First is the class name
    def self.first_ac
        "first"
    end
  end
end
```

sec.rb

```
module Udp
  class Sec
    def self.sec_ac
        "sec"
    end
  end
end
```

config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/adapters/**/*"]
```

I am trying to access:
Articles_controller

```
def index
  msg = Article.invite
  render text: msg
end
```

Article.rb

```
def self.invite
    msg = Udp::First.first_ac
    msg
end
```

Please help me solving it.

Comment: It's not just because your folder is Udb (note the b at the end) and your module is Udp (note the p at the end) is it? Or was that a typo in the question?

Comment: I am sorry. It is a typing mistake. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by editing `/config/environments/development.rb` as below

```
config.eager_load = true
```